# I cannot get the files in Android's external sd card programmatically

Tags: android, file

When I try the code below:

```
File home = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

File [] f = home.listFiles();
```

I cannot get the files in the sd card, can anyone explain why?
and the path of the external directory  is `/storage/emulated/0/`

Thank you

Comment: what kind of error you are facing ?

Comment: Have you used read permission . If not write this line in Android Manifest .<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: post any logcat stacktrace..

Comment: I cannot post a logcat because I don't own an android device.

Comment: I got the feedback from a few friends that I sent the APK to.

Comment: But I know it's not a problem with anything else because when I use the following code, it runs fine and displays the files

Comment: File home=new File("/");

Comment: @Harsha have you tried my answer ?

Comment: I actually used the permission before and actually I'm not looking for one particular file, but all the files and folders in one directory.

Comment: ok, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638293/how-to-list-all-files-and-folders-locating-on-sd-card

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory usually doesn't actually return _external_ sd card in traditional sense (noted in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())), but rather internal sd card (it _is_ external to the `/data` though). Is this what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using emulator with API-24/25 ..

Unfortunately with both you have no access to storage. I have no idea id that was intended to be change or its just a bug

You can check if you have access to your storage by `adb shell ls`

**You must use Emulator with API-23 or less to be able to access storage.**

Comment: actually it was the feedback that I got from another person using a mobile.