# List folder content on sdcard

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display mp3 files in a specific folder on `sdcard/myaudio`, I found this example:

[How to list all files and folders locating on sd card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638293/how-to-list-all-files-and-folders-locating-on-sd-card?fbclid=IwAR3fJ9ZMLjOUJYD9L0xmVqOnhJrT4ktAgSyjqsR4fEq_-bnOhR-2i-K3C4M#8639261)

I write the sdcard name and folder in the first method, but the app is crashing

this is what I have done until now

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    file = new File(root_sd + "/sdcard/myaudio");
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        myList.add(list[i].getName());
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList));

}
```

Please some help.

update

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private File file;
String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    checkAndCreateDirectory();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        fillList();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
    }
}

private void fillList() {
    String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File file = new File(root_sd + "/sdcard/myaudio");
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        myList.add(list[i].getName());
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList));
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                fillList();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void checkAndCreateDirectory() {
}

public void checkAndCreateDirectory(String dirName){
    File new_dir = new File( root_sd + "/sdcard/myaudio/" );
    if( !new_dir.exists() ){
        new_dir.mkdirs();
    }
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    File temp_file = new File(file, myList.get(position));

    if (!temp_file.isFile()) {
        file = new File(file, myList.get(position));
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        myList.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            myList.add(list[i].getName());
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList));
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    String parent = file.getParent().toString();
    file = new File(parent);
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    myList.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        myList.add(list[i].getName());
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), parent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList));
}
```

}

Comment: What is the errorlog ? and are u sure your folder is already there ?

Comment: that path with `/sdcard` is most likely wrong.

Comment: yes, I'm sure there is a folder

Answer (score 0):

Your `file.listFiles();` may be null. It can happen due to an empty folder or specific folder is not there.

You can use below method to check if the folder is already there otherwise create it.

```
 public void checkAndCreateDirectory(String dirName){
        File new_dir = new File( rootDir + dirName );
        if( !new_dir.exists() ){
             new_dir.mkdirs();
        }
    }
```

you can avoid a crash when the folder is empty by adding the following null check

```
File list[] = file.listFiles(); 
if(list == null) return;
```

Comment: I made the method (checkAndCreateDirectory) and call it after onCreate, but it's still crashing, this is the error message  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.listfiles/com.example.android.listfiles.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: did u add if(list == null) return; part @colla it will avoid crash.

Comment: Now I can display the files on the screen, but I cannot play the mp3 files, would help me in this please

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your app does not have the permission to read the external storage.  
Write this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

just before the `<application` tag in your `manifest.xml`
Put this declaration:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

instead of inside `onCreate()` at the class level (before `onCreate()`) to make it visible anywhere in your activity class.  
Create this method:

```
private void fillList() {
    String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File file = new File(root_sd + "/datanfile");
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        myList.add(list[i].getName());
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList));       
}
```

and in `onCreate()` have this code only:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  ???????
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        fillList();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
    }
}
```

This way your app will ask for the necessary permission if it is not already granted.  
 Now you will get whether the user granted this permission, by overriding `onRequestPermissionsResult()` :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                fillList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above method is invoked after the user has accepted or not to grant your app the permission.
So `fillList()` will be executed if your app has already the permission, or after the user grants the permission. It will not be executed if the user does not grant the permission. 
**Edit**
In the `onCreate()` method you posted there is no `setContentView()`. Why?
**Edit2**
In your code you have:

```
private void checkAndCreateDirectory() {
}

public void checkAndCreateDirectory(String dirName){
    File new_dir = new File( root_sd + "/sdcard/myaudio/" );
    if( !new_dir.exists() ){
        new_dir.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

Delete the 1st and remove `String dirName` from the 2nd

Comment: Sir, I put the filelist method after onCreate, the if condition inside onCreate and onRequestPermissionsResult method outside onCreate, but sadly it's still crashing, please some help

Comment: At the start does the app request permissions?

Comment: Yes Sir, it's requesting for permission, this is new, thank you very much, but after that immediately crash

Comment: I can't say anything about it, because the code you posted is not indicative of the problem. If you do have created a subfoler `myaudio` inside `sdcard` folder then your list should contain all there is inside `myaudio`. After that I think you want to fill a ListView but I don't know anything it. So put a breakpoint inside `fillList()` method and debug to find where the next problem is.

Comment: @cola Why there is no `setContentView()` inside the onCreate() method?

Comment: I update the question and post all the code what I done now, you are right there is no setContentView(), I add it but it's still crashing

Comment: I'm trying to put the code but I get error message (Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.)

Comment: What is this? This is not an AppCompatActivity, it's a ListActivity. Why did you create this kind of activity?

Comment: because i want to create listview, and without it I get many errors like (cannot resolve methode (setListAdapter) and cannot resolve method (onListItemClick) ) both of these errors will removed when i'm using ListActivity

Comment: Do you know how to handle a ListActivity? I don't because I have never used one.

Comment: Sir, for info I forget to say I'm new in android studio

Comment: Then you must start from the basics: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity and find tutorials all over the net, especially on youtube. But don't try to start something you don't understand. And don't expect that others will write all the code for you.

Comment: I already create the listview and give it the id, is this what do you mean by handling?  for this example, I don't think there is some thing else needed, so no professional work needed